# "clang: error: no such file or directory: '2' clang: error: no input files" error in Visual Studio Code on MacBook Pro

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm on the most recent version of Visual Studio Code. When I was practicing c++ before the class, Visual Studio Code created a different folder. When I moved my Assignment 1.cpp file from the default path, the program also wouldn't work on VSU.
"clang: error: no such file or directory: '2'
clang: error: no input files"

[code+error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh6jj.png)

[explorer path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfhsl.png)

Comment: It would appear that whatever build command you are using is not prepared for paths with spaces in them.

Comment: It's best to never use a space in a filename or path in `c` or `c++`. Even though the IDE may be a GUI the actual building happens  with a command line compiler. On the command line a space separates separate arguments requiring quotes to make it into one. Sadly still in 2022 quoting is not always automatic or it fails some of the time so its best to just avoid it.

Comment: In your first picture you can see the problem with the space. It tried to compile `Assigmnent` and `2.cpp` and said these files do not exist because there are no quotes around `Assignment 2.cpp`

Comment: I removed the spaces in the file name, and the IDE didn't give me that error. Now I know that I shouldn't use spaces in file names. I would upvote the comments, but all I see is a flag. Regardless, thanks for the help! :)